# Unable to establish SSL connection when downloading MODIS tiles in R

Tags: r, modis, hdf, ssl

Using R I've successfully used NASA's MODIS to download NDVI data for two studies, but now I'm getting this error repetitively:

```
    ############################
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\PROGRA~2\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2020-04-24 08:31:46--  https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD13Q1.006/2019.11.17/MOD13Q1.A2019321.h09v04.006.2019337231330.hdf
Resolving e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov... 152.61.133.130
Connecting to e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov|152.61.133.130|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
Remote connection failed! Re-try: 18 
Getting file from: LAADS 
############################
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\PROGRA~2\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2020-04-24 08:31:47--  https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MOD13Q1/2019/321/MOD13Q1.A2019321.h09v04.006.2019337231330.hdf
Resolving ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov... 198.118.194.40
Connecting to ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov|198.118.194.40|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
Remote connection failed! Re-try: 19 
Getting file from: LPDAAC 
############################
```

This is a sample of what I am using to download MODIS data:

```
getProduct("MOD13Q1")
getProduct("MYD13Q1")
print("begin download")
tfs <- MODIS::runGdal(product = "MOD13Q1", collection = "006"
               ,tileH = 9, tileV = 4
               ,begin = "2020.01.01"
               ,end = "2020.04.10"
               ,job = "temporalComposite" # prevents new directory with timestamp from being created
               #,SDSstring = "100000000010"
               ,outDirPath = "./MODIS3/MOD13Q1.006"
               ,overwrite = TRUE)
```

It took about an hour to acquire data for two different tiles successfully. But then it took 26 hours to acquire data for another AND when downloaded the data was corrupt. Anyone familiar with SSL networking that can explain what went wrong?

Comment: not a GIS issue, but a network issue?

Comment: > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817876/wget-ssl-alert-handshake-failure